# SQL unique index explaination

Tags: sql

I have seen this for the first time. This is a section in liquibase for defining the unique columns in a table. But I don't understand which columns are unique.

```
<sql dbms="postgresql">
        CREATE UNIQUE INDEX
        invoice_tax_id_null_index ON
        invoice_table
        (invoice_profit_id, invoice_account_id, tax_id,
        country_id,
        COALESCE(invoice_tax_id, -1))
    </sql>
```

Are all of the columns mentioned here unique? For example

```
invoice_tax_id
invoice_profit_id
invoice_account_id
tax_id
country_id
```

Or is only

```
invoice_tax_id
```

unique?

How to read that? Thank you very much.

Comment: The combination of all values is unique. Ie there can be no two rows with (1,1,1,1,1) but there can be one row with (1,1,1,1,1) and another one with (1,1,1,1,2) and yet another one with (2,1,1,1,1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unique index specifies 5 columns, so generally this means that no two records in the `invoice_table` can have the same 5 values at the same time.  Attempting to do an insert with 5 values already existing in some other record would generate an error.

Comment: That is: no column needs to be unique, only all columns together.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen ok, thank you very much. And if we wanted to use the spring boot annotation UniqueConstraints do I need to do something like that:

{UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"invoice_tax_id", "invoice_profit_id", "invoice_account_id", "tax_id", "country_id")}

Comment: @Blnpwr Yes, that should instruct JPA to create this unique index on the table (if it doesn't already exist there).